# How to manage the font size between retina and the normal design

Tags: website-design, sketch-app, css, html

I am mocking up a one page website using sketch in macbook pro retina with the resolution of 1440width and 5120height. I see everything perfect once my design is done, but when I start coding the html and css with my thunderbolt I see the font sizes are bigger than the one I am seeing in my retina display. So what would be the better solution to have a better design in normal window and as well as retina window. I use 1x and 2x images for retina and normal window but I am not pretty sure about font sizes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to halve the size of the images for "normal" size, then you would need to halve the size of the type to be proportional. If your retina display requires 2x pixel size images, then your retina display requires 2x (pixel size) type.

Comment: Do you mean (for example) a font set to 24pt in your HTML/CSS looks bigger than a 24pt font in your design app?

Comment: @Mysterfxit yes that's the exact thing I'm facing

Comment: Which one seems like numbers match what you expect them to be? The layout or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If working @2x in your design program you can double the PPI setting for the document, but leave the pixel dimensions the same.

So if your document is 1440x1520 @ 72ppi change it to 1440x1520 @144dpi

That will leave everything looking the exact same but now your font sizes will more closely match what you will eventually code in CSS.

Or you can just divide all the font sizes by 2.

Comment: I tried dividing the font sizes by 2 but still in some places they are looking too small. I mean when I divide 20/2 it's 10 it's not visible 

Comment: In your CSS what units are you using for font sizes? i.e. px, pt, or em

Comment: I do use pixels just as it was used in sketch app

Comment: Hmm...this is how I usually work in Photoshop and it works for me. I'm not familiar with Sketch. Maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: points are relative to inches, so you don't simply divide 24pt by two, you need to convert it to pixels. This is what you are doing by flagging everything at a higher dpi (the software is making that calculation for you)

Comment: @Yorik Generally no, but in my example yes you can divide by two.

Comment: @Yorik  I hit enter too quickly on the last comment. I know it's not perfectly accurate, but I usually I just take the Photoshop point number and use that for pixels in CSS and that gets me within about 10% and I just fudge it a bit in CSS to get it to look right.  How do you convert between pixels and points?

Comment: @Mysterfxit: I forgot to mark my comment to Benjamin, as it was directed more towards his first comment to your answer. DPI setting in images is merely a flag or indicator of intent, but in "inch-aware" software, the DPI setting is a scale factor used for calculating type sizes etc. as your answer illustrates.

Answer (score 0):

I have to view my files at 200% to see what images/text will look like in browser. This also caught me by surprise when getting retina display.